# Регулярные выражения PHP Метасимволы

Tags: php

есть строка с вариантами ответа в виде { }{ }{ { } } нужно написать регулярки для того чтобы открыть скобки, то что внутри скобок не важно, чисто наполнение в плане логического сравнения

помогите составить регулярные выражения или метасимволы для функции `preg_replace_callback()` для удаления скобок

избавление от сравнения уже есть:

```
$variants = explode('|', $str); // избавление от сравнения |
```

Comment: Я один ничего не понял?

Comment: чего не понятного? есть строка с вариантами ответа в виде { }{ }{ { } }
нужно написать регулярки для того чтобы открыть скобки, то что внутри скобок не важно, чисто наполнение в плане логического сравнения

Comment: Ну дак так и написали бы в своем посту с вопросом, как в этом комментарии.

Comment: Если вам нужно удаление скобок, то регулярки тут не нужны - можно использовать str_replace(), передавая первым параметром массив со скобками.